# Getting Current time to display in Label. VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to build a Break tracker for work and I would like to get a button to display the Current Time in a label. I have tried multiple solutions and this is how far I have gotten.

```
Sub AddButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)        
        Dim Start as Integer
        System.DateTime.Now = Start
        total.Text = Start      
End Sub
```

When I do this, I get the error that Property 'Now' is read only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try This.....

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load    
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label12.Text = TimeOfDay.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `TimeOfDay` here? If it's a `TimeSpan` (presumably from `DateTime.Now`) then I wouldn't expect this to work - `tt` is valid for `DateTime`, but not `TimeSpan` formatting. (And you'd need to escape the colon.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Please refer this link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hhbhw4c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Wow, that's even nastier than using TimeSpan. But yes, it'll work. I'd generally suggest not using VB-specific properties though.

Comment: @JonSkeet Why don't you like VB?

Comment: While I'm not a fan of its various quirks, I don't think I actually said anything against VB here... I just suggested not using VB-specific properties. That's very different.

Answer (score 13):

There are several problems here:

- Your assignment is the wrong way round; you're trying to assign a value to `DateTime.Now` instead of `Start`
- `DateTime.Now` is a value of type `DateTime`, not `Integer`, so the assignment wouldn't work anyway
- There's no need to have the `Start` variable anyway; it's doing no good
- `total.Text` is a property of type `String` - not `DateTime` *or* `Integer`

(Some of these would only show up at execution time unless you have `Option Strict` on, which you really should.)

You should use:

```
total.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()
```

... possibly specifying a culture and/or format specifier if you want the result in a particular format.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Now Just to set up a Diff in minutes and I'm done. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user2602702 Subtracting one `DateTime` from another results in a `TimeSpan` which has a `TotalMinutes` property (a `Double`) which should tell you what you need to Know....

Comment: @user2602702: The answer you've now accepted doesn't look like it would work, to me - could you clarify what's missing from this answer, so I can improve it?

Answer (score 3):

try

```
total.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()
```

or

```
Dim theDate As DateTime = System.DateTime.Now
total.Text = theDate.ToString()
```

You declare `Start` as an `Integer`, while you are trying to put a `DateTime` in it, which is not possible.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Date.Now` instead of `DateTime.Now`

Comment: @Mayur Looks to me like this is an answer (albeit a short answer).  An answer should only be deleted if it is a question or "thanks" posted as an answer, or if it's a link-only answer; short answers or wrong answers  should not be deleted.  See [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue).

Comment: This does not answer what the OP is trying to do. You cannot fix assigning variables in the wrong order by simply changing the way a system variable is referenced.